# libc++ - naming conflict for bind()?

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

After surprisingly little hacking about, I managed to get libc++ installed on my Linux box (as libstdc++ is missing things). Unfortunately, a bit of my existing code has now broken, on account of functions with the same name.

Normally, and in the manner I need, bind() relates to sockets. However, libc++ came with its own bind() function, which is basically [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/bind/bind.html) but without a convenient namespace to separate them. In accordance with Murphy's Law, the compiler attempts to use the wrong function, and spits out an error. NetBeans does not see any issue, because it's actually looking in the sys/socket.h file, as it very well should.

So, with both functions basically beyond the scope of my control, how would I tell the compiler (clang++) that it should look in a specific header and nowhere else for that function?

Comment: Give some context, e.g. the order of you include directories and the link order. At what stage does this error occur?

Comment: @honk I have now tried every permutation of directory order and link order, on the off-chance that would solve it. No luck. As best I can tell, the "-stdlib=libc++" compiler option takes precedence over anything I can set in my files.

Comment: libc++'s `bind()` is in the `std` namespace. Socket's `bind()` should be in the global namespace. Are you using `using namespace std;` anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this hasn't anything to do with Murphy, I'd think: the choice of the `bind()` template is probably just the better match. The declaration of `std::bind()` is in namespace `std`, however, at least in the version of the header file I'm looking at. Is it possible that your source file contains a using directive? (in which case you deserve all the pain you asked for)

If there is no using directive, the non-template version should be a better match if the arguments match **exactly**. If this still doesn't help, you can create a forwarding function for the `bind()` function from `<sys/socket.h>`, let's say `avoid_conflict_bind()` which is the only function defined in the translation unit, i.e. it would only include `<sys/socket.h>` and not `<functional>`. This way there is no choice for the `bind()` function this function forwards to and you can then use `avoid_conflict_bind()`.

Comment: I do indeed have `using namespace std;` in all my source files, since so much relies on that. I shall try dropping in a function outside its scope that redirects bind().

Comment: Personally, I'd rather remove the using directive from all source files but this choice is yours. Since I don't have using directives myself I'm a bit vague on this but I **think** that using `::bind()` doesn't use the names imported via a using directive. This may be a bit simpler. I **strongly** recommend against using directives, however! It just makes it unclear where functionality came from. I'm using explicit qualification (normally using a namespace alias) everywhere: it is straight forward to see what a declaration refers to.

Comment: @DigitalMan: I second Dietmar Kuhl's opinion on `using namespace xxx;`. You have several alternatives instead: 1. Fully qualifying the types (the functions should be picked up by ADL), 2. using `typedef` for oft used types, 3. bringing oft used types (or functions) in scope by a targetted `using std::string;` (for example), 4. using namespace aliases for long-winded namespaces `namespace phx = boost::phoenix;`. Remember than in general you should try to have the smallest possible scope for your symbols.

Comment: Well now. I did quite a bit of looking, and it seems a ubiquitous belief that, once a 'using' is in place, it can not be avoided within that code block. But, lo and behold, `::bind()` accomplished precisely that. And using one '::' certainly beats using a hundred 'std::' elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

I had a conflict between `bind()` from `<WinSock2.h>` and `std::bind()` (I was using `using namespace std;`)
 I just added `::` before the method call and it worked !
`bind()` => `::bind()`

Comment: I had the same problem. I followed your guideline. It works. Thanks